# How can I set a custom DNS server within Nixos?

Tags: dns, nixos, nix

I've not found much information in the manual.

I've tried to manually modify the file `/etc/resolv.conf` however this seems to be overwritten by something?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16):

```
networking.nameservers = [ "1.1.1.1" "9.9.9.9" ];
```

Comment: Docs: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-networking.nameservers

Comment: What file path should this line be added to?

Comment: @JayWhitsitt Everything in NixOS should be configured via `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` (unless you use flakes), so you should add it there. See https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-changing-config and https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#ch-configuration for more info.

Answer (score 4):

```
  environment.etc = {
    "resolv.conf".text = "nameserver 192.168.0.32\n";
  };
```

Adding the above to my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` seems to work.